# Association of new records with a particular object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have 'project_list' and 'project_detail' pages. Inside 'project_detail' page I have button which redirect user to 'project_members' page where they can add new members to current project. How to associate a new created members with the current project. I am little bit confused with view. Whats the best way to realise it?

**models.py**:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ***FIELDS***
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership',)

ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('developer', 'Developer'),
        ('business_analyst', 'Business analyst'),
        ('system_analysts', 'System analysts'),
)

class Membership (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ProjectMembersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        exclude = ('project',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectMembersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['role'].choices = tuple(choice for choice in ROLE_CHOICES if choice[0] not in ['manager'])
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^project/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', project_detail, name='project_detail'),

    url(r'^project/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/members$', project_members, name='project_members'),
]
```

**view.py**:

```
def project_members(request, slug):
    if slug:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            members_form = ProjectMembersForm(request.POST)
            if members_form.is_valid():
                members_form.save()
            else:
                members_form = ProjectMembersForm(instance=request.user)
            return render(request, 'project/project_members.html', {'members_form': members_form,})
```

Comment: So the form should show all users in the `User` table and allow to add/remove them as members to the project?

Comment: How about: `NON_MAANGER_CHOICES = ROLE_CHOICES[1:]`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answer few days ago. You need add this to **views.py**:

```
***
new_member = form.save(commit=False)
new_member.project = project  # Add this line
new_member.save()
***
```